# recursive parser combinator (string)

Tags: parsing, haskell, recursion, parser-combinators

I'm reading Programming in Haskell by G. Hutton and got confused in chapter 8 (Parsers). I can't understand how string parser works recursively. Here's the code (I've rewritten it explicitly using >>= because do notation abstracts even more stuff).

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]

failure :: Parser a
failure = \ inp -> []

return :: a -> Parser a
return v = \ inp -> [(v, inp)]

item :: Parser Char
item = \ inp -> case inp of
                [] -> []
                (x : xs) -> [(x, xs)]

(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
p >>= f = \ inp -> case parse p inp of
                   [] -> []
                   [(v, out)] -> parse (f v) out

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
parse p inp = p inp

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char x = sat (== x)

sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p = item >>= \ ch -> if p ch then return ch else failure
```

Clear so far to me, but now I don't see how recursively string would work.

```
string :: String -> Parser String
string [] = return []
string (x:xs) = (char x) >>= \ _ ->
                string xs >>= \ _ ->
                return (x:xs)
```

Can someone rewrite every step of recursion on a simple input: e.g. `string "he" "hell"` which should return `[("he","ll")]`. Here's how I start.

```
string ('h':['e']) "hell"

((char 'h') >>= \ _ -> string ['e'] >>= \ _ -> return('h':['e'])) "hell"

(\ inp -> case parse (char 'h') inp of
         [] -> []
         [(v, out)] -> parse ((\ _ -> string ['e'] >>= \ _ -> return('h':['e']) v) out) "hell"

parse ((\ _ -> string ['e'] >>= \ _ -> return('h':['e']) 'h') "ell"

(string ['e'] >>= \ _ -> return('h':['e'])) "ell"

(\ inp -> case parse (string ['e']) "ell" of
          [] -> []
          [('e', "ll")] -> parse ((\ _ return(['h','e']) 'e')) "ll"

((\ _ return "he") 'e') "ll"

return "he" "ll"

[("he", "ll")]
```

Comment: After a cursory look, it looks fine to me. Keep on expanding `string ['e']` and `>>>` so to reduce it to something involving `string []`. This is analogous to what you have already done.

Comment: OK, I guess I've managed to get the result via substitution skipping the recursive step, which will produce `string [] "ll"` call which will result in `[("","ll")]`. So, then is returning a failure from `char x` the only case when we we hit `[] -> []` case in `>>=`

Comment: Minor typos aside (e.g. `['he']` should be `['h','e']` or `"he"`), the new version looks OK. The possible failures are indeed generated by `char`: either because the string is empty, or because the char found in the string differs from the `char` argument.

Comment: Thanks, this has been the most complex recursion definition in the book so far, took me a while to comprehend it. Will continue with the exercises.